# Change from wayland to xorg in ubuntu 22.04 mouse doesn't work in login screen

Tags: xorg, mouse, wayland

When I set WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and reboot (or sudo systemctl restart gdm3) the mouse does not respond and I can't log in.  Is there a way to fix this?  I have an nvidia Quadro P620 card.

Comment: Try ```CTRL + ALT + F3``` then reboot. there change WaylandEnable=true using nano and finally reboot your system

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F3 doesn't work for me when xorg is enabled, only under wayland.  Fortunately I can ssh into my computer to change to WaylandEnable=true.  Your solution doesn't solve my problem, I want to be able to use Xorg.

Comment: You need to install the proper Nvidia drivers and disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: Thanks ChanganAuto.  Updating the drivers was difficult, but it eventually solved the problem.